# How to assign class to an element using $scope variable in angular js

Tags: javascript, css, angularjs, ng-class

I have a class

```
.haba-haba{
border:1px solid red;
height:50%;
width:50%;
}
```

I am storing the class name in scope variable in my controller using

```
$scope.className = "haba-haba";
```

How can I assign `$scope.className` to my `div` as a class?

I tried doing `<div ng-class="'{{className:true}}'"></div>` It didn't work.

Anyone can tell me a solution? thanks in advance!

Comment: I don't think that storing `$scope.className = "haba-haba";` is a good idea. Which class to use is view's concern, not model's concern. You should hard-code the classes in view and based on the conditions to apply classes accordingly.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The syntax for the `ngClass` directive is this:

`ng-class="{'haba-haba': thruthValue}"`

where

`$scope.thruthValue = true;`

You can obviously replace `true` with `false` or a function that returns `true` or `false`.

Another usage is this:

`ng-class="getTheClass()"`

where

```
$scope.getTheClass = function() {
    return 'haba-haba';
}
```

[Here's a working fiddle of the second usage.](http://jsfiddle.net/24sqQ/1/)

Also, as other people have pointed out, the second usage is totally against sane MVC.
Don't use it unless you know what you are doing.

Comment: Could you please post your code? What's not working? Does it throw any exceptions? Check your dev console.

Comment: problem is that this function is not called.

Comment: @SergiuParaschiv is that a valid code? 'ng-class="getTheClass()"' ??

Comment: But where is ng-class used in this example?

Answer (score -1):

Actually, what you should do with `ng-class` is create a boolean variable and attach it to the `ng-class` attribute - when this boolean is `true` - the div has that class:

```
$scope.toggleClass = false;

ng-class="{'haba-haba' : toggleClass}"
```

Now when you set `toggleClass` to `true` - your div gets `haba-haba` added.

Comment: This can not be the answer.

Comment: @AdityaPonkshe -- Care to explain?

Comment: @tymeJY OP wants to use value stored in scope, to use as a class, not by setting flags

Comment: @AdityaPonkshe -- Not a very smart way to do it IMO - the point of markup like `ng-class` is to know exactly what is happening in the view in a clean way. Having your class name stored in a variable and using said variable in the markup creates confusion.

Comment: that maybe true but if OP wants to do it his way we should provide exact solution, you can still provide alternate solution but should mention why, in the answer, like u did in a comment